# How to get the known values of variables I store in a Java Object?

Tags: java, object, double

I read a JSON and stored data into different objects. I stored some coordinates in a class named `Geometry`. The class looks like this:

```
public class Geometry {

    private Object[] coordinates;
    private String type;

    public Object[] getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }
}
```

As you can see, `coordinates` field is an array of class `Object`.

Knowing that `coordinates` will always have 2 positions (2 coordinates) and that the type of those coordinates is `double`, how can I get the `double` value of the coordinates?

To be more exact, what do I have to write on the following method for the system to return the two coordinates explicitly?

```
public double[] returnCoordinates() {
    double[] coord;

    coord[0] = //?
    coord[1] = //?

    return coord;
}
```

Comment: Why does `Geometry` have `Object[]` instead of `double[]` (or `Double[]`) if you know they're going to be doubles?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Kayaman the JSON stores the doubles in format `Object[ ]` I have already tried changing the type to `Double[ ]` or `double[ ]` and I get an Exception

Comment: It is probably also worth mentioning that you should show how you're deserializing and potentially serializing.

Comment: @user157629 what kind of exception?

Comment: @Kayaman `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY`

Comment: That sounds odd. So `private Double[] coordinates;` made Gson expect an object? Now I know Gson is way quirkier compared to for example Jackson, but it should be able to deserialize doubles.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to store an array, or even a Collection, of Coordinate objects inside of the Geometry object. If you're not already using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) look into it, it will make life very easy.

```java
class Coordinate {

    private final double x;

    private final double y;

    public Coordinate(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Geometry {

    private final Collection<Coordinate> coordinates;

    private final String type;

    public Geometry(Collection<Coordinate> coordinates, String type) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Collection<Coordinate> getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly I'm using Gson, I'll take a look tho, thanks!

Comment: If you're using Gson that is great.